# iOS FBSDKLoginManager get email

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, email

I followed the Facebook tutorial for the SDK here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0

My problem is that I can get user informations but I cannot get the email, it's not in the current profile. I have the first name, last name, user id, etc..

Where can I find the email field because when I do this
"if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])"

it tells me that the user has granted the email.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried the following:

```
if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) { 
    NSLog(@"Granted all permission");
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
           if (!error) {
               NSLog(@"%@",result);
           }
        }];
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"Not granted");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

add one parameter 'email' to get email of current user. From i think SDK version 4.9, 'fields' parameter is compulsory to get user email. (I didn't check for the previous SDK versions though)

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
{
    NSDictionary *param = @{@"fields" : @"email"};
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:param] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
                    NSLog(@"%@",result);
                }
    }];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make user that you requested a permission for the **email**

```
 let requestMe:FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "id,email, first_name, last_name, gender, picture"])


    let connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()



            connection.add(requestMe, completionHandler: { (con, results, error) in

                //access_token

                if ((error) == nil)

                {


                    let dic = results as! NSDictionary

                    let email = (dic.value(forKey: "email"))




                }
                else

                {


                }

            })


            connection.start()
```